# How do I position these images in a responsive way?

Tags: css, frontend, web-frontend

I'm not sure how to position these images on a webpage properly - here's a rough outline of the [positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMRYl.png) (the squares are the images).

I know I need to use absolute positioning because the images overlap each other, but I'm not sure how to make this responsive without using a lot of media queries.

Here's the code for my attempt:

```
    <section id="homepage">
      <img src={Square} alt="blah" className='image image1'/>
      <img src={Square} alt="blah" className='image image2'/>
      <img src={Square} alt="blah" className='image image3'/>
    </section>
```

```
#homepage {
    height: 100vh;
    background: #ffb6b6;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20vw;
}

.image1 {
    top: 18vh;
    left: 27vw;
}

.image2 {
    top: 30vh;  
    left: 50vw;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.image3 {
    top: 40vh;
    right: 27vw;
}
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've updated with code. Thanks!

Comment: What`s wrong with the code? Do you not want them to overlap?

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you want them overlapping but works best in an equal x and y view as shown on your example. If you do not want them overlapping, change the image size to 33.3 Let me know if I have understood your problem correctly.

If you want them to stay fixed then put them in a fixed size container and adjust the image size accordingly, there is enough for you to play around with hopefully.

The images have been placed inside DIVs as it makes positioning easier I think anyway.

```css
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background: #ffb6b6;
}

#homepage {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #ffb6b6;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.image {
   width: 50vw;
   height: auto;
}

.image1 {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}

.image2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.image3 {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:3;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
    <div id="homepage">
      <div class='image1'><img src='https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/41.jpg' alt="blah" class='image'/></div>
      <div class='image2'><img src='https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/42.jpg' alt="blah" class='image'/></div>
      <div class='image3'><img src='https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/43.jpg' alt="blah" class='image'/></div>

    </div>
```